# How to match a URL at end of a line with regex

Tags: regex, url

I have to find a pattern for matching only the URL's of a list like this:

```
one | two | three | four | http://www.site/whatever-the-site-uses
one | two | three | four | http://www.site/whatever-the-site-uses
one | two | three | four | http://www.site/whatever-the-site-uses
```

i need to grab the whole http or https inside a SINGLE GROUP but I can't get a good pattern for it

Can someone help me? So far, I have `\|(.*?)/$`, but the result is something like

```
| two | three | four | http://www.site/whatever-the-site-uses
```

Comment: stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.  have you tried anything on your own so far?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to explain at the problem that i need all the result to be at one single group (inside the parenthesis), that's my biggest issue about that problem

Comment: i tried many codes of my own, but none of them gave me the correct result... my last try was something like that: \|(.*?)/$ but i got the the result since the first pipelne

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/WDuhbH/3

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i need the pattern to have a single group. I'm currently trying to use the /$ to get started in the end of the line, but so far i'm having trouble to hit the correct | : \|(.*?)/$ 

this regex takes "| two | three | four | http://www.site/whatever-the-site-uses"

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand you right? From the last "| https://" capture the group staring with *https?* to the end of the line

Is this it?

```
/\|\ (https?\:\/\/.*)$/
```